# Android installing service apk programatically - getting parser error

Tags: java, android, service, android-install-apk

I am trying to install an service apk from within my code only to get the following error:

```
Parse error
There was a problem while parsing the package
```

I have tried installing the apk from within the assets, raw folders and SD card. However I keep getting the same parsing issue.

Below is the code I am currently using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/filename.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

I have verified that the apk itself is not the issue, by installing the apk direct from my phone, which worked perfectly.

Is there something that I am missing from my code, a specific permission or anything else?

Comment: Are you renaming the apk file before installing

Comment: No I do not rename the apk

Comment: Post the code where you are copying the apk from assets to sdcard

Comment: I am not doing this via code at present, I physically placed the apk directly onto my devices sd card by plugging it into my PC via usb.

Comment: you must be copying the apk from assets folder to sdcard then launching the install intent. right? So paste that code.ohh okay i got it now

Comment: No I am currently not doing it that way, I don't even have the apk within the project directory. I upload the apk externally using a USB connection to my PC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125695/discussion-between-landl-partners-and-manishika).